# python requests: globally add http header to every request

Tags: python, docker, python-requests, http-headers

I'm looking for a way to globally add an http header to all requests made with python requests. The idea is that this will be running in a Docker container, and I don't want the person/script making calls to `request.get` and `request.post` to have to explicitly add headers to the request every time. Does requests have any sort of global pre-request hook or some other way to modify the request via global configuration?

Comment: You can use a `Session()` with headers.

Comment: Would setting the header as an environment variable and then importing it with  `os.environ' work?

Comment: Thank you @KlausD and @Trace Malloc. Those approaches require that the person/script making the request needs to add that explicitly. I was hoping that there might be a way to configure that such that those headers could automatically be injected and a user/script does not have to set that manually; I was hoping to add the header for any outgoing request, whether the person/script explicitly sets the header or not. Perhaps if requests has a configuration file that would globally execute a pre-request script or something. Or I suppose I could monkeypatch `requests`, but don't like that?